# Memory-Leaks / Memory handling Issues in Solr

Tags: memory-leaks, solr, weblogic

I am using **solr-3.6** deployed in Weblogic server. My Index will be updated through **delta-import** every 5 seconds.

Normally, there is no problem with the Solr. But I came across an error in the log saying,
"SolrIndexWriter was not closed prior to finalize(), indicates a bug -- **POSSIBLE RESOURCE 
LEAK!!!**". I sometimes have seen the **outofmemory** exception as well. Unless we restart, solr becomes dis-functional under these circumstances.

Please suggest the best strategy to handle these memory issues in solr, when handling an index of order **10 million** documents out of which some are updated every **5 seconds** through delta import.

Comment: in solrconfig.xml do you have an <autocommit> setting? If so, perhaps, you could utilize the approach described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930101/documents-are-reflecting-after-some-delay-in-solr-3-6 In case that does not work for you, but you still have the autocommit on, try tweaking that parameter so that SOLR would not commit too often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to make the Garbage collection on the Weblogic stream more aggressive this will prolong the life of the application and reduce/stop failures due to out of memory issues.

Here is a great link to help you tune the GC for the weblogic instance. I also recommend setting the min and max memory the same, this can cause issues also, depending on what WLS version you are running.

[Weblogic GC Tuning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12529_01/wlss31/configwlss/jvmgc.html)

Comment: @Mavellin Feel free to click the up arrow if you found that info useful. Or tick the answer if it solved your issue.